# Why is my Python code returning a list of characters instead of items?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, p-lang

Question:

I'm trying to solve the following problem: given two arrays of strings list1 and list2, find the common strings with the least index sum.

A common string is a string that appeared in both list1 and list2. A common string with the least index sum is a common string such that if it appeared at `list1[i]` and `list2[j]` then `i + j` should be the minimum value among all the other common strings. I need to return all the common strings with the least index sum.

Here's the code that I've written so far:

```
class Solution:
    def findRestaurant(self, list1: List[str], list2: List[str]) -> List[str]:
        res = []
        smallest_n = float('inf')
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            if list1[i] in list2:
                res.append(list1[i])
        if len(res) == 0:
            return False
        if len(res) == 1:
            return res.pop()
        if len(res) > 1:
            for i in range(len(res)):
                n = list1.index(res[i]) + list2.index(res[i])
                if n < smallest_n:
                    smallest_n = n
            result = []
            for i in range(len(res)):
                n = list1.index(res[i]) + list2.index(res[i])
                if n == smallest_n:
                    result.append(res[i])
            return result
```

My issue is that the code is returning a list of characters instead of items. How can I modify my code so that it returns the expected list of items instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to return a list of the least index sum string with each item being a word, but instead, I returned the (correct) result as a list of characters of the word.

I attempted to change the `result.append(res[i])` to `result.append(str(res[i])`, but I got the same result.

Edit: an example of an input with unexpected results would be:

````
["Shogun","Tapioca Express","Burger King","KFC"]
["Piatti","The Grill at Torrey Pines","Hungry Hunter Steakhouse","Shogun"]
Output:
["S","h","o","g","u","n"]
Expected:
["Shogun"]```

Edit: thank you very much for all the help, the error was using .pop() to return the only value in the list rather than the list itself.
````

Comment: Can you give an example of input values (`list1` and `list2`) that give unexpected results?

Comment: Thanks. So, if the answer is a single string, you should still return a list containing that single string. But `return res.pop()` returns that string itself, not wrapped in a list. The checker is probably doing something like `for x in answer:` which when `answer` is a string, iterates over its characters.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at function definition

```
class Solution:
    def findRestaurant(self, list1: List[str], list2: List[str]) -> List[str]:
```

As you can see from the highlighted part the expected output is `List` of `str`

As @slothrop pointed out in the comment `res.pop()` which is the operation being performed on `List` of `str` if we look at `pop` function definition

```
 |  pop(self, index=-1, /)
 |      Remove and return item at index (default last).
 |      
 |      Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.
```

It return item if present, if index provided then remove item at index and return or if item not found raises error.

Since `res` is `List` as defined in first line of the function body which contains `str` item which is what gets returned in this case `Shogan` string.

To fix the issue you can just directly return `res` which is `List` only containing single item `Shogan` string and what is expected in return as per function definition

The output `["S","h","o","g","u","n"]` which is printed by platform checker As @slothrop pointed is probably looping over the string or trying to convert it to list `list('Shogan')` and then compare with expected output